# Type hinting dict with key/value type pairs

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, type-hinting

Is it possible with Python type hints to specify the types of a dictionary's keys and values as pairs ?

For instance :

- If key is an `int`, value should be a `str`
- If key is a `str`, value should be an `int`

If I write :

```
Dict[Union[int, str], Union[int, str]]
```

it allows `str -> str` and `int -> int`, which are not allowed.

And with :

```
Union[Dict[int, str], Dict[str, int]]
```

the dictionary can be **either** a `Dict[int, str]` or `Dict[str, int]`, but not both at the same time ...

I also looked into `TypedDict`, but it requires to give explicitly all the keys.

Comment: I don't think that's something you can encode at the type level at this time. Would it make sense in your code to use two separate dicts, one `Dict[int, str]` and one `Dict[str, int]`, instead?

Comment: Basically, you want to make the static value type a function of the *dynamic* (runtime) key type.

Comment: I also think @chepner ist right, if you mix key and value types in a dict then it should be any. You should use two different dicts if you want to ensure types via hinting.

Answer (score 3):

If using `typing.cast` is acceptable for your application, then this can be done by making a class that subclasses `Dict` that has overrides for `__setitem__` and `__getitem__`, casting your dict to that type. From then on, type checkers will infer correct `KeyType: ValueType` pairs.

The caveats of this approach are that you can't use it to type check proper dict construction, as that happens before the cast. Additionally, you would need to add more overrides for things like `update`, `__iter__` and possibly other dict methods to get type checking for things beyond `__setitem__`/`__getitem__` dict access.

Example:

```py
from typing import Dict, overload, cast


class KVTypePairedDict(Dict):
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, key: str) -> int: ...
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, key: int) -> str: ...
    def __getitem__(self, key): ...

    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, key: str, value: int) -> None: ...
    @overload
    def __setitem__(self, key: int, value: str) -> None: ...
    def __setitem__(self, key, value): ...


test: KVTypePairedDict = cast(KVTypePairedDict, {"foo": 0, 1: "bar"})

# str keys
a: int = test["foo"]
test["foo"] = 0
c: str = test["foo"]  # <-- mypy and PyCharm flag this
test["foo"] = "bar"  # <-- mypy and PyCharm flag this

# int keys
d: str = test[1]
test[1] = "bar"
b: int = test[0]  # <-- mypy and PyCharm flag this
test[1] = 0  # <-- mypy and PyCharm flag this
```